# Switching axis in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, axis

[image]

I'm trying to switch the axes on this graph, so that SMI is on the x axis and number is on the y. That's what a lecturer told me to do anyway. If that's right, how do I do it? If not, why should I keep it like that?

*the data goes down to about cell 98*

[image: Graph and a bit of the data I used]

Comment: Show some Data, SMI and corresponding numbers

Comment: " If thats right, how do I do it? If not, why should I keep it like that?" - whether it's right or not is off-topic here. What you've tried to change axes? It should be simple: right click on chart, select data, switch...

Comment: If a professor asked you to do this, I'm assuming it means they've taught this subject to you previously. Is this a homework question?

Answer (score 1):

When you chart data in Excel, each series in a chart has a SERIES formula. Click on the series and look in the formula bar. The formula looks like this:

```
=SERIES(Sheet1!$C$2,Sheet1!$B$3:$B$102,Sheet1!$C$3:$C$102,1)
```

The syntax is

```
=SERIES([name],[x values],[y values],[plot order])
```

You can edit this formula right in the formula bar. Simply copy and paste to put the X and Y addresses in the order you need (note that B and C are switched):

```
=SERIES(Sheet1!$C$2,Sheet1!$C$3:$C$102,Sheet1!$B$3:$B$102,1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Copy the data, under paste options click transpose. Accidentally worked this out after trying for ages. Hope this helps someone out!